# Why phonegap adds contacts in the outlook account?

Tags: javascript, cordova

this is my code. Im trying to add a contact to an android phone. It works but I don't know why the contact is saved in the outlook contacts instead of phone contacts memory.
It Also happens that Im getting an error code 0 when I try to save but the contact is saved anyway.

```
function onSuccess(contact) {
    alert("Contacto" + txtEntGuardarComo.val() + " guardado con correctamente.");
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
};

var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
contact.displayName = txtEntGuardarComo.val();
contact.nickname = txtEntContacto.val();

var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = txtEntNombre1.val();
name.familyName = txtEntNombre2.val();
contact.name = name;
contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: No, i'm using titanium appcelerator and now life is good :)